# NSIndexPath crash on iOS5

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios5

My App worked fine up until iOS5.

I have a grouped tableview with 2 sections. Each section has 1 selection, that is displayed with a UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.

My App crashed in iOS5 when I try to determine `if([lastIndexPath1 isEqual:indexPath])`

UPDATED: Entire relevant code below:

lastIndexPath1 and lastIndexPath2 are both NSIndexPath objects that i have declared in the header. Number 1 keeps track of the last indexPath in section 0 and number 2 keeps track of section 1.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{



 [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  

//Initialize the array.
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *fontName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Baskerville", @"Palatino", @"Times New Roman", @"Verdana", nil];
NSDictionary *fontNameInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fontName forKey:@"FontOptions"];

NSArray *fontSize = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", @"Der var engang", nil];
NSDictionary *fontSizeInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fontSize forKey:@"FontOptions"];

[listOfItems addObject:fontNameInDict];
[listOfItems addObject:fontSizeInDict];


}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


     NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //SET SKRIFTTYPE 
    NSString *neverOpendFonts1 = [prefs objectForKey:@"neverOpendFonts1"];  

    if (![neverOpendFonts1 isEqualToString:@"1"]) {



            lastIndexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

            UITableViewCell *newCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath1]; 

            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 

            NSString *lastIndexPathString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];

            [prefs setObject:lastIndexPathString1 forKey:@"lastIndexPath1"];

            NSString *fontName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Palatino"];

            [prefs setObject:fontName forKey:@"fontName"];

            neverOpendFonts1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];

            [prefs setObject:neverOpendFonts1 forKey:@"neverOpendFonts1"];

            [prefs synchronize];

            NSLog(@"Har aldrig været åbnet - font options"); 


    }

    else
    {
        NSInteger row = [[prefs objectForKey:@"lastIndexPath1"] intValue];

        NSLog(@"FONT ROW: %i", row);

        lastIndexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];

        UITableViewCell *newCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath1]; 

        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 

    }
 //SET SKRIFT STØRRELSE


    NSString *neverOpendFonts2 = [prefs objectForKey:@"neverOpendFonts2"];  

    if (![neverOpendFonts2 isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {

        lastIndexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];

        UITableViewCell *newCell2 = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath2]; 

        newCell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 

        NSString *lastIndexPathString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];

        [prefs setObject:lastIndexPathString2 forKey:@"lastIndexPath2"];

        NSString *fontSize = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"24.0"];  

        [prefs setObject:fontSize forKey:@"fontSize"];

        neverOpendFonts2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];

        [prefs setObject:neverOpendFonts2 forKey:@"neverOpendFonts2"];

        [prefs synchronize];

        }

        else {

            lastIndexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];

            UITableViewCell *newCell3 = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath2]; 

            newCell3.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 

            NSString *lastIndexPathString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];

            [prefs setObject:lastIndexPathString2 forKey:@"lastIndexPath2"];

            NSString *fontSize = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"16.0"];  

            [prefs setObject:fontSize forKey:@"fontSize"];

            neverOpendFonts2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];

            [prefs setObject:neverOpendFonts2 forKey:@"neverOpendFonts2"];

            [prefs synchronize];
        }

    }

    else
    {

        NSInteger row2 = [[prefs objectForKey:@"lastIndexPath2"] intValue];

        NSLog(@"FONTSIZE ROW: %i", row2);

       lastIndexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row2 inSection:1];

        UITableViewCell *newCell2 = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath2]; 

        newCell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 


    }

    [myTableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Number of rows it should expect should be based on the section
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"FontOptions"];
    return [array count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [listOfItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...

    //First get the dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"FontOptions"];
    NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;


    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {

        if([lastIndexPath1 isEqual:indexPath])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else 
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
             cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville" size:24];   
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
              cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:24];    
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:24];  
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
               cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:24];   
            }
                break;
        }

    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {


        if([lastIndexPath2 isEqual:indexPath])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else 
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:16];   
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:20];    
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:24];  
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:28];   
            }
                break;
            case 4:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:32];   
            }
                break;
            case 5:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:36];   
            }
                break;
            case 6:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:40];   
            }
                break;
            case 7:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:44];   
            }
                break;
            case 8:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:48];   
            }
                break;
            case 9:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:52];   
            }
                break;
            case 10:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:56];   
            }
                break;
            case 11:
            {
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino" size:60];   
            }
                break;
        }


        }


        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Does the console tell you anything about the error? Or, at least, is the error a SIGABRT or an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Yes I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Sorry about not being clear on that... If I comment out the if([lastIndexPath1 isEqual:indexPath]) function, the App runs fine...

Comment: Where exactly are you doing the comparison and how do you store the values?

Comment: I am doing the comparison in: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath... If I set the values wit integers I get the error as well. Only a problem on iOS5

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried to use if(lastIndexPath1 == indexPath) ?

Comment: Yes have just tried that, but it seems to have no effect. The App does not crash at that point, but somewhere else, and there is not set any checkmarks is the process... I will update my question with the entire code... Maybe that will help...

Comment: How is lastIndexPath1 defined, with what properties?. Can you try to use self.lastIndexPath1 all thru the class?

Comment: Yes it is defined like this in the header:   NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath1; and @property (nonatomic,retain) NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath1; and in the .m i synthesize lastIndexPath1;

Comment: It I comment out the if([lastIndexPath1 isEqual:indexPath]) function, the App loads fine. I just noticed that when I close the view, I get the same error in my dealloc af [lastIndexPath 1 release]; Could I be initializing it wrong?

Comment: @ott YEAH!!! You are right! did a self.lastIndexPath1 and self.lastIndexPath2 in from of them all, and it did the trick! iOS5 is apparently more sensitive about that... Convert your comment to an answer, and I will award it as the right one... THANKS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How is lastIndexPath1 defined, with what properties?. Can you try to use self.lastIndexPath1 all thru the class?

Comment: Like richerd commented, the problem origin is in retaining the object. self.indexPath = ... Makes sure you call the retain setter if the property is marked "retain" - In case of non-properties you should retain/release yourself

Comment: I got the same issue for supporting app on iOS 5.0, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You are not retaining last index path.

```
    lastIndexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
```

[NSIndexPath indexPathforRow:row inSection:0] returns an autoreleased object, at the end of the next event loop it is released if it is not retained.

try

```
[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] retain];
```

i'm assuming your not compiling under Xcode 4 and ARC

you really should be using property accessors to handle the memory management for your lastIndexPath1 variable

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath lastIndexPath1;
```

then `@synthesize lastIndexPath1;`

whenever you assign lastIndexPath use `self.lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath ....]`